# What is the best way to store files(photo and video) in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know which way is better to use about uploading and saving a file in my local server.
for example I see someone that INSERT image's link in the mysql field, I'm confused right now...
I want to upload some files and show that in other situation...
what's the best and secure way to perform that?

Comment: why do you want to store the in a *database* (especially in mysql) ?

Comment: You can store binary files in a blob (or binary) column. You'll probably want to store information about the files in other columns (file type, etc.). This is if you want to store the _actual_ file in the database. There are pros and cons to this approach. I often argue that it's better to store files on the file system (which is more suited to that sort of thing) and store references to those files in the database (which you allude to with "image's link in the mysql field), such as a web path or absolute local path. It's using the right tool for the job, but you have to keep the data in sync.

Comment: note: search here on SO, I've seen many similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all the images in a folder called `photos` for example. Then, save an index of the file in your database assigning it an index number and other information. Save the file in the photos folder, renaming it `[index_number].jpg`, or whatever extension is needed. For example, if I upload the file `coolpic.jpg`, it will be assigned an index number of 2845. The file itself is saved in `photos/2845.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Saving in Database may make some problems like as DB performance decrease (as result of reading and writing big files), DB crashes (as a result of delete of edits of rows fields), **backup problems** (because of huge dump file, some problems when table needs to be repaired.
also read file from mySQL will be delivered by Apache again. 
I suggest you use of normal path with rewrite mode (virtual url)

Comment: I mean DB overload and server load.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use img link.. its not necessary and all it does is just making you DB larger.

You shoud store just "picture.jpg"

and in documents use `<img src="images/'.$row['image'].'">`

Even better, you can create a function for it (displaying pictures).

Like

```
function DImage($image)
{
//you can do miracles here like checking images types, if is file and so on, padding, even adding divs and vspaces..

$output = '<img src="imagesfolder/'.$image.'">';
return $output;

}
```

so latter all you have to do is..
echo DImage($row['image']);

PS: if you ask about $_POST & $_FILE uploading, of course.. it is impossible for you to maintain images, names and updates I'm sure..